# Sorting a SortedDictionary Requires a Different Key from OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorteddictionary, sortedcontainers

I am having trouble sorting a dictionary based on key values, which are originally strings. I am looking for a solution that uses [`SortedDict`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html). Below I cast the strings to `int`, but the sorting seems irrational.

```
#using Jenks' library:
from sortedcontainers.sorteddict import SortedDict

mydict = SortedDict(
        lambda k: int(k[0]),
        {
        '1': '#fe70ac',
        '10': '#ff7400',
        '11': '#b6a2d1',
        '12': '#79bc3b',
        '100': '#000000',
        '101': '#000000',
        '102': '#000000'
        })
```

Returns

```
SortedDict_items(
[('11', '#b6a2d1'),
('10', '#ff7400'),
('12', '#79bc3b'),
('1', '#fe70ac'),
('102', '#000000'),
('100', '#000000'),
('101', '#000000')....
```

Comment: Can you sort the dict later while iterating over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you replace `int(k[0])` with `int(k)` because otherwise you're sorting your dict based on the first digit of the key.

Comment: Brilliant. The key is not the same as for an `OrderedDict`, where `OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))` and `KEY=0`, `VALUE=1`.